# Como chamar uma função js no html

Tags: javascript

Bom não tenho certeza mas acho que o erro está na forma em que estou chamando a função js. Segue o código:

```
createdCell: function(td, cellData, rowData, row, col){
                    //td:       a coluna em questão
                    //cellData: dados da linha inteira
                    //rowData:  dados da linha inteira
                    //row:      index da linha
                    //col:      index da coluna


                    $(td).html(`<a class="btn btn-primary" onclick='${editar(cellData,row)}'>Editar</a>`); 
                }
```

Desta forma quando eu abro a página ela já abre o modal de alteração que deveria disparar somente quando o botão for clicado.
Código da função que eu estou chamando:

```
var editar = function( dados2, linha2 ) {
var dados = dt.data();
console.log(dados2);
console.log(linha2);
$( '#alterarModal' ).modal();
for ( var i in dados ) {

    if ( i == linha2) {
        $( '#alt_nome' ).val( dados2.nome );
        $( '#alt_siape' ).val( dados2.siape );
        $( '#alt_cpf' ).val( dados2.cpf );
        $( '#alt_funcao' ).val( dados2.funcao );
        $( '#alt_codigo' ).val( dados2.codigo );
        $( '#alt_nivel' ).val( dados2.nivel );
        $( '#alt_unidade' ).val( dados2.unidade );
        $( '#alt_portaria' ).val( dados2.portaria );
        $( '#alt_publicacao' ).val( dados2.publicacao );
        $( '#alt_ingresso' ).val( dados2.ingresso );
        $( '#alt_exoneracao' ).val( dados2.exoneracao );
        $( '#alt_sub_nome' ).val( dados2.subnome );
        $( '#alt_sub_siape' ).val( dados2.subsiape );
        $( '#alt_sub_cpf' ).val( dados2.subcpf );
        $( '#alt_sub_ingresso' ).val( dados2.subingresso );
        $( '#alt_sub_exoneracao' ).val( dados2.subexoneracao );
        $( '#alt_sub_publicacao' ).val( dados2.subpublicacao );
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Não percebo o que queres fazer com esse código... podes explicar o que queres fazer?

Answer (score 2):

Você está montando o HTML dentro de uma string template, portanto o que tiver de JS ali no meio, entre `${}`, será executado. Você deve alterar:

```
${editar(cellData,row)}
```

para

```
editar(${cellData},${row}).
```

E dependendo dos tipos de `cellData` e `row` talvez você precise de aspas simples em torno delas, na saída final.